# cURL, como alterar o país de origem

Tags: libcurl

Usei *cURL* para logar automático no Facebook, mas alguns minutos depois, recebi uma mensagem dizendo que alguém havia acessado minha conta dos *Estados Unidos*, e por questões de segurança eles perguntaram se foi eu..

Então, acredito que o *cURL* usa o servidor para acessar a URL que eu havia definido no `curl_setopt`, com isso o servidor deve estar localizado lá(*EUA*)..

A questão é, há uma maneira de corrigir isso? Acredito que seja algo com cabeçalhos *HTTP*, enfim, agradeço se puderem abrir um pouco minha mente para até mesmo me indicar quem sabe um tutorial de como funciona o cURL.

Comment: Tente o seguinte, vou deixar como comentário pois não sei se encaixaria como resposta ou solução ao seu caso. Entre no facebook no site, abra o console (f12 - chrome), vá até a aba network, procure pelo principal (normalmente primeiro da lista), entre na aba headers. Analise os headers (request-headers) que são passados e tente montar o cURL parecido. Mais informações como usar os headers -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115683/php-curl-custom-headers

Comment: Rafael, irei ler mais sobre sua resposta, valeu! Daniel, na verdade é sobre como contornar a situação, é que eu fiz uma pergunta e já puxei mais uma, vou arrumar o post.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft, eu li alguma coisa, e não achei nada com isso. Mas percebi que facebook se baseia pelo IP para representar uma cidade aproximada, e o IP que acessei ontem era do servidor e ele colocou como Desconhecido, acredito que só pegando um servidor do Brasil, ou simplesmente permitindo o IP desconhecido(dizendo ao Facebook que fui eu que acessei..).
Agradeço pela resposta, acabei lendo mais sobre headers de requisição e de resposta, foi de ajuda para mim.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus é realmente já vi algo sobre esse tratamento de ip, ficaria ainda pior se o usuário tivesse em suas configurações de segurança o bloqueio de acesso para essas requisições estranhas ou de um computador desconhecido...

Answer (score 0):

A única forma de fazer isso é utilizando `PROXY`, o IP é a única coisa que identifica a localização do acesso.

O CURL tem suporte para PROXY de várias maneiras, você pode utilizar por exemplo:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

O `$proxy` terá que ter o valor do tipo:

```
[user:password@]ip[:port]
```

Por exemplo:

```
$proxy = 'usuario:abc@111.222.333.444:8888'
```

---

Os proxies podem ser adquiridos, o seu custo é extremamente variável, dependendo do local, da qualidade de conexão e também o limite de uso. Você pode adquirir o próprio servidor e utiliza-lo como proxy, usando por exemplo o `Squid Proxy`, que é um software destinado para criação de proxy. *Como uma outra opção é utilizar o `TOR`, ele pode ser utilizado como proxy e é gratuito, neste caso o IP seria `127.0.0.1:9050`, se estiver rodando na maquina local, e você deve configurar o `exit node` para o destino que quer nas configurações.*

Isso irá fazer exatamente:

```
Seu servidor (Nova Iorque) -> Seu proxy (São Paulo) -> Facebook
```

Dessa forma o Facebook irá reconhecer que a conexão ocorreu em São Paulo, se São Paulo for próximo (ou exatamente) onde você se conecta normalmente não haverá bloqueio. :D