# Usar IP ou LOCAL que o usuário está (ou o mais perto disso), para enviar uma consulta

Tags: php, javascript, libcurl

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function getpage($url, $postdata=''){
    $c = curl_init(); <br>
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false); 

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)
    AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'); 
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1); <br>
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

O que acontece é que até consigo usar um proxy, mais não é bem isso que quero. Veja como ficaria com proxy:

```
   function getpage($url, $postdata=''){
   $proxy = 'UM-IP';
   $porta = 'A-PORTA';
   $c = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $porta);
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);

   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) 
   AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2'); 
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

O que eu desejo fazer é quando o usuário entrar na página do meu site, e inserir os dados que serão solicitados. que a consulta seja executada, e mostre que isso foi feito talvez pelo IP dele ou de um ponto perto dele.

Já tentei muitas formas, mas sem sucesso.

Tenho dúvida de porque não funciona quando eu coloco no proxy: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` e na porta: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']`?

Ao meu ver isso estaria solicitando o ip dele mais a porta, só que quando tento usar, não funciona. Como posso conseguir isso?

Obrigado pelas respostas, mas essa função de descobrir o IP já consigo facilmente com esses códigos:

```
function getpage($url, $postdata='')  
{  
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {  
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];  
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {  
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];  
} else {  
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
}  
echo $ip;
```

O que preciso agora, não sei se é algo simples, mas estou procurando a tempo é como faço para implantar de forma correta no código que tenho:

```
$c = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)   AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2');  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
```

Talvez essa linha:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

Mas mesmo eu trocando `$proxy` por `$ip`, ainda assim não da certo. Já li todos os links que foram passados também, e fiz muitos testes mais ainda sem sucesso.

Comment: Acredito que aquele site que você passou como exemplo vá contra as regras aceitas na comunidade. Removi da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Função para obter o IP PHP
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
}

//Server para obter IP do Cliente
function get_client_ip() {
$ipaddress = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
    $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
return $ipaddress;
}
```

Eu tinha esta funcção para uma situação idêntica e comigo funcionava, espero que consiga também

Comment: -1 Isso tem vulnerabilidades graves de segurança, permitindo IP Spoofing. Você confia no cabeçalho enviado pelo usuário, ou seja, se enviar `curl seusite.com -H "X-Forwarded-For: 123.123.123.123"` você vai pegar o IP falso. Fora que o `X_FORWARDED_FOR` (não sei o resto) pode ter vários IPs, ou seja `111.111.111.111, 222.222.222.222`, de qualquer maneira ele não é confiável.

Answer (score 0):

[É exatamente o mesmo dessa pergunta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53820/curl-como-alterar-o-pa%C3%ADs-de-origem/) O que estar querendo fazer não é possível, ao menos não é possível somente um um mero site. *Além de haver falhas de segurança no código, mas vou ignorar isso.*

---

Para que você utilize algum IP [como proxy ele deve ser um proxy](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy#Programas), ou seja ele deve ser um servidor de proxy. *Inclusive, muitos malwares fazem isso justamente para que aquele dispositivo infectado sirva como proxy.*

Em geral é o mesmo que eu pegar o seu IP e querer fazer `http://(seu-ip)` e esperar que um site abra, isso funcionará somente se seu IP tiver algum servidor HTTP ligado, no mais dará erro de conexão ao seu IP usando HTTP.

*Se não fosse assim qualquer um poderia spoofar um IP simplesmente usando como proxy um IP alheio.*

---

**Como que eles fazem?**

Simples, contrate servidores de proxy ao redor do mundo e utilize o proxy mais perto da localidade da pessoa ou contrate servidores e instale um [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Intro/). *Uma outra opção é criar um software instalável na maquina do cliente (um aplicativo para smartphone e um programa instalável no PC) que possa executar tal requisição, logicamente ela vai partir usando o IP do cliente.*

Existem [várias e várias empresas](https://proxy.info/proxy/index) que vendem proxies ao redor do mundo, por exemplo:

- http://blazingseollc.com/proxy/
- http://www.anonymous-proxies.net/index.php?r=site/coverage
- http://www.limeproxies.com/network-status.php
- http://www.bestproxyandvpn.com/buy-proxies.html

Existem também serviços conhecido como "backconnect proxies", eles são IPs de redes residenciais, normalmente originado de botnet, não há como saber o origem desses IPs e desses servidores. Eles também mudam o IP a cada X minutos na maioria das vezes, são eles:

- https://microleaves.com
- https://buyproxies.io
- https://5socks.net

> **Não tenho vinculo com qualquer site mencionado acima!**

A outra solução, como mencionei, é ter o seu próprio servidor de proxy, por exemplo usando o [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Intro/), dessa forma basta que contrate servidores dedicados ao redor do mundo e instale o software. Agora, no cURL você conseguirá conectar nele e usa-lo como proxy, *logicamente requer algumas configurações*.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, foram de grande ajuda;